# Assume $E[X^2]=20$. Find the mean and variance of $X$ if the mean and variance are equal.

Tags: probability

I've never seen a problem like this before. We're given that $E[X^2]=20$ and that the mean and variance of $X$ are equal. The task is to find the mean and variance given this information.

I wish I could say I tried everything, but I'm honestly clueless as to where I should even begin. I tried setting $Y = X^2$ to rewrite the random variable, but I don't think that helps at all.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Use the fact that

$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$$

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution. However, I do get 2 distinct solutions in -5 and 4.

Comment: Did you know that $Var(X)\ge0$?

Comment: Right, because it's the sum of the squared differences. My bad.